Movie where a guy is protecting a kid, and gets shot in a mall while the kid plays a VR game?
I'm really sorry about how few details I've got about this movie, but I saw part of it on TV when I was a kid, and I honestly don't remember much about it at all.
All I remember is that the ending scene took place in a mall. While this one child (whom I think the bad guy was trying to either abduct or murder) was playing a VR game at a kiosk, the hero and the antagonist were tracking each other through the mall. The bad guy saw the hero, drew a bead on him, and then in slow-motion started moving the gun to point at the kid. The hero jumped in front of the bullet and got shot before falling into a fountain.
I've been absolutely sure that I saw this for over a decade now, but nobody I've asked seems to remember anything like it.

It doesn't exactly fit your description, but the movie "Cloak and Dagger" (1984) sounds similar. The movie centers around a video game that has hidden government codes in it. Towards the end, the bad guys are chasing the main character who is a small boy through a river walk area. It doesn't have a fountain, but centers around the canal of the river walk. The 'hero' jumps in to save the boy from getting shot and he gets shot instead. He's essentially the boy's imaginary friend, who is a loose depiction of the boy's deceased father. There's no VR headset or anything, just the video game.

First kid?
Sin bad?
Disney channel? I don't know.

You'd be surprised how much the following details can help: What year (approximately) did you watch the movie? Was it live action, or animation? What country did you see it in? Was it in color?

Also, is there any chance either the protagonist or antagonist was Arnold Schwarzenegger? I seem to recall such a movie and picture him in it.

@DenialViana that's my guess as well.  You should post an answer.

@druciferre Sorry for not responding sooner. I posted this after drinking heavily one night, and completely forgot that I had posted it. Anyway, I saw the movie around 2003-2005, it was live action, I saw it in the US, and it was in color.

@CJPatong No, that's not it. T2 is one of my favorite movies, and it's not the one.

This is First Kid featuring Sinbad.
In it Sam Simms (Sinbad) is the body guard of the President's 13 year old son Luke.
The movie ends with a scene in a mall where Simms gets shot protecting Luke.
Here is a picture of Luke playing the VR game at the mall:


That's exactly it! Thank you!

This reminds me of Mercury Rising.
In the end of the film, Bruce Willis' character is shooting it out with a bad guy while trying to protect an autistic kid he's been protecting through the whole film. Ultimately he does get shot himself (as I recall).
Without knowing some other details, it's kind of hard to tell though (as other comments have mentioned). However, the movie was released in 1998 (more than a decade ago), features a guy protecting a kid from agents wanting to capture/kill the kid, no VR for the kid though (nothing I remember), and it takes place in a skyscraper with windows breaking/crashing, Bruce's character falls through a glass conservatory after he's shot, etc.
Been a while since I've seen it, so I might be off a bit on some things. Hope this helps though.
(I'd leave a comment, but not enough rep yet)

I'll give Mercury Rising a watch to see if that's it.
